# Is it better to use php time() function if there is no provision of timezone in database

Tags: php

I have to update a currently running application to work in multiple countries. Current database doesn't has any provision for time-zone of users. I am thinking to implement the creation/modification of records in unix seconds available from time(). Tried to look for it but couldn't find anything concrete, I don't have support to test in multiple time-zones right now.

Update: UI is not part of php api server.

Comment: I would avoid using UNIX timestamp, otherwise, you'll get upset in [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: And php doesn't care about the client timezone, getting the `time()`, `date()` or a `new DateTime()` will be based on the server time and date not the client

Comment: actually only the apis are in php, ui is separate in an html portal, so as of current testing, record created in australia are showing correct local time in India and Australia, but you are right, I should consider the application lifespan to cover 2038 issue

Comment: Since the UI is using Javascript so server date time in a fix timezone can be converted to local timezone, I think this will fix my issue.

Comment: The x64 builds of PHP 7 support native 64-bit integers, LFS, 64-bit memory_limit and much more, which means that problem will not be there in supported systems.

Answer (score -2):

```
file: getTime.php
<?php
    $intClientTime=$_GET['intClentTime'];
    $intServerTime=time();

    echo $intClientTime;
    echo $intServerTime;
?>
<script>
    var objDate    = new Date();
    var objXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    objXHR.open('GET', 'getTime.php?intClientTime='+objDate.getTime());
    objXHR.onload = function()
         {
         var strStatus=objXHR.status;
         if(strStatus===200)
                {
                console.log('date sended');
                }
         else
                {
                console.log('Error');
                }
         };
         objXHR.send();
</script>
```